# Exporting to Excel .xlsx from a Python Pyramid project

Tags: python, xls, xlsx, xlwt, openpyxl

I know about the XLWT library, which I've used before on a Django project. XLWT is very neat but as far as I know, it doesn't support .xlsx which is the biggest obstacle in my case. I'm probably going to be dealing with more than 2**16 rows of information. Is there any other mature similar library? Or even better, is there a fork for the XLWT with this added functionality? I know there are libraries in C#, but if a python implementation already exists, it would be a lot better.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty good.  I used it for a couple of small things:

http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/

Comment: I tested it in the shell and it seems pretty good. How good is it dealing with say... millions of rows? Also, if I'm doing a query in a site powered by Pyramid and SQLAlchemy, how does it handle the load with the optimized writer? Will the browser time out?

Comment: I tried it with about 2-3 thousand rows so I can't comment.  If you are doing millions of rows or the process is time consuming, I'd make it an "offline" process initiated from a web page and save the file somewhere.  When the export is complete, you can then mail a link to the user so they can collect it.  It saves blocking the browser.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Or maybe when the export file is clicked, it shows a progress bar then provides a link to the user to download when it is finished processing. I know that XLWT is ok with exporting really big files without letting the browser timeout, but I think using it is out of the question since I'd have to split the rows across many worksheets if it reaches the limit.

Comment: XLSX has a higher row limit than XLS so should be ok.

Comment: Can Openpyxl return an XLSX file to the browser as a response (attachment file) without calling the workbook.save()? I don't want to have any writing to disk happening, everything should be done in memory, is it possible?

Comment: See the following - it allows you to write to a StringIO buffer and that can be pushed to the output: https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/src/d0fa6490e219/openpyxl/writer/excel.py#cl-145

Comment: Nice, it works. I came upon a problem when trying to write a Python Decimal value to a cell. It doesn't accept it, but it does if I cast it to a float. The traceback tells it has to be 'string or buffer.' What's the best way to do this in this situation?

Comment: I'd just str(x) it to cast it to a string.

Comment: If one wants a number in an Excel spreadsheet, one should explicitly write a number. Converting (Python doesn't do casts!) a Decimal value to float is much more preferable than converting it to str. Non-conversion of Decimal to float should be raised as a defect with the library maintainer.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Yes, I agree, it raises an error when you try to write a Decimal value into a cell, so it's the library's fault. Does anyone know how to format values such as date to obey the format I want?

Comment: @chiurox: Re formatting, we don't have crystal balls, what is the format that you want? I suggest tha you start a separate question.

Comment: @JohnMachin: I'd like to format dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format when it's just a date. When it contains time, then DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. Also for numbers, I want comma to separate a decimal, not period.

Comment: Regarding the comment about "millions of rows": the .xlsx format only supports 1048576 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Another really good alternative, actually what I switched to from Openpyxl is TabLib.

http://tablib.org

Comment: It would help others if you explained why.

Comment: TabLib supports not only XLSX but also JSON, HTML, CSV, etc.
I actually implemented exporting with both libraries.

Comment: Tablib uses xlwt for its .xls support and openpyxl for its .xlsx support.

Answer (score 0):

Export a CSV don't use .xlsx..

Comment: Not an alternative for me at the moment. It's an internal application where everyone wants it in .xlsx.